# How can we assess the importance of the features even if we ended up applying PCA?

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering

There are multiple techniques to analyze the feature importance (permutations, SHAP values, etc).

It is essential that, in order to improve the interpretability of the model, we can somehow map the transformed features to the original ones. For example, when we assess the feature importance of encoded features, we can somehow see what are the encoded variables related to primordial ones that are predominant at the top score/weight entries.

But, how can we assess the feature importance when we apply feature reduction techniques like PCA that can dramatically reduce the number of features and the interpretability of the model?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes we loose interpretability such way. You can only try to remove features one by one from you process to see how it affects score of model so you will know how important each of your features.